# codeigniter Cart issue with insert data

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-cookies, shopping-cart

i am new to code-igniter. here i am using shopping cart for product checkout. when i am add product to cart it's working for first three products, after adding any product consider as fourth product. if any product add to cart after three products it will replace the existing fourth product. but only first three product display on cart, and the fourth one not display and also i cant add more than four products on cart, i am using jquery ajax for cart update

jquery ajax code

```
$('.addcart').click(function(){
    var proid=$(this).attr('id');           
    $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>productajax',{typ:'addtocart',proid:proid},function(data){           

    })
    return false;
})

product add to cart code



 $proid=$this->input->post('proid');
                    $this->db->where('pro_id',$proid);
                    $data=$this->db->get('product')->result();
                    foreach ($data as $pro)
                    {
                        $proname=$pro->pro_name;
                        $price=$pro->s1price;

                        $proimg=$pro->image_name;
                        $nwt=$pro->case_netweight;
                        $gwt=$pro->case_grossweight;
                        $cbm=$pro->cbm;
                    }

                    $propriceinr =round($price + round(($price * $this->session->userdata('user_margin'))/100,2));          

                    $dat = array(
                   'id'      => $proid,
                   'qty'     => 1,
                   'price'   => $propriceinr,
                   'name'    => $proname,
                   'options' => array('cbm' => $cbm, 'nwt' => $nwt,'gwt'=>$gwt,'image' => $proimg ,'price'=>$price,)
                );              
                    $this->cart->insert($dat);
```

config.php

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

i don't know the product cart why not update after insert three product. give me a guidance for this issue anyone. thanks advance

Comment: show the `config.php` `session` settings in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set

`$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;`

to `$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;` in your `config.php`.

Right now your products details are being saved in **cookie** which has the maximum limit of **4kb**.
By enabling `$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;`.

This feature  lets you insert your information in database table i.e:

`$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';`.

Hope that will work for you

If you dont have `ci_sessions` table here is the query for that:

```
 CREATE TABLE `ci_sessions` (
 `session_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ip_address` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `user_agent` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `last_activity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`user_data` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: in ci_sessions what are the column name i have to create for cart ??

Comment: No need to create any column.

Comment: just create table as empty structure ?? i have an error because i dont have table name like this in my db it's gave some error

Comment: @tamil_arvu do you have `ci_sessions` table in your database ??

Comment: No i dont have ci_session table in my db

Comment: it's gave error when insert data too long . but i extended length for user_agent . yeah it's working. thanks bro. may i know why it's happening

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable csrf protection in application/config/config.php

```
$config['csrf_protection']  = FALSE;
```

Then, if ajax call start working, enable it again and add ci_csrf_token variable to ajax call.